# Subversion 1.9 revprops not recording author name

Tags: svn

upgraded from subversion 1.6 to 1.9

for new commit, the author is not recorded in ../revprops/ log file

root@jupiter:/var/db/svn/BudgetEngine/db/revprops/17 # more 17385

K 8

svn:date

V 27

2019-09-16T05:46:05.182922Z

K 7

svn:log

V 4

test

END

I can edit the commit property from Eclipse, then the author name can be recorded properly, new section K 10

root@jupiter:/var/db/svn/BudgetEngine/db/revprops/17 # more 17385

K 10

svn:author

V 3

jyu

K 8

svn:date

V 27

2019-09-16T05:46:05.182922Z

K 7

svn:log

V 4

test

END

How can I configure the subversoin to record svn:author name upon commit?

Comment: Do you maybe have some hook that strips svn:author on commits?

Answer (score 0):

It is really up to the server configuration and/or the protocol you used to access the repository when you committed.  For example, if you committed via http/https then it would be up to how Apache was configured and whether it forced the user to provide credentials. Apache would then set the internal variable that tells SVN what the author name was.

In short, start by looking at what protocol you used ... file:// svn:// or http:// then review the configuration.

Nothing in SVN has ever changed in this area.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out. In version 1.6, svn can take HTTP site level authentication user name as author name. In version 1.8 and 1.9, svn no longer honors the HTTPP authentication user name, it requires its own svn authentication to get author name. So I added authentication inside svn location in http_conf, then the author name can be recorded in svn log.